# Javascript 'redirect' without page reload

Tags: javascript, hash

This question has been asked before but I need a more cross-browser* option not the git-hub one.

Is there anyway to change :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/test#hey
```

to :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/test
```

using javascript without reloading the page ? (hitting the server again)

*by 'more cross-browser' I mean IE7+ FF3.5+, not IE6, etc

Comment: What's the aim? Functionally there should be no difference, right?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear since you're not saying what it is that you want to do. The first URL will force the browser to scroll to the anchor within the page, the second one will "hit" the server and ask for the resource. There's no way to change the URL to display what you want it to be without actually forcing the browser to do something with the URL.

Comment: And what's “the git-hub one”?

Comment: It's complicated which is why I didn't go into detail ! The thing is that if a user clicked a link to a hash anchor, the page would jump and not reload. If I do it via javascript, the page reloads.

Comment: Anyone who's tried to do this will know it's possible using the same technique as git-hub use ! Which does work but is updated browser dependent

Answer (score 2):

You could use `history.pushState()` for this.

This will remove the hash:

```
history.replaceState( {}, '', location.href.split('#')[0] );
```

For cross-browser compatibility, you could use [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) as a polyfill.

Comment: @Daisy: that's still browser-dependent: you'll need FF4 or newer Chrome or Safari browsers. Everything else doesn't support `history.pushState/replaceState`.

Comment: @Marcel: Hence the polyfill ;)

Comment: Oops, I can't remember seeing the last line. But doesn't it do the same as the code in Madmartigan's answer?

Comment: @Marcel - History.js fixes HTML5 browsers implementations of the HTML5 History API and provides a backwards compatible experience for HTML4 browsers. @Madmartigan answer doesn't care for the HTML5 History API at all.